# JSON changing enums value in List of enums back to 0

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, enums

I have a class which has multiple variables that are all correctly created via a JSON text file except for one list of enums which belong to an Effects class

the below class always has the enums in the effectedBy list defaulted to element 0

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InteractableObject : Item, IEffectReceiver
{
    protected List<Stats> stats = new List<Stats>();
    protected HashSet<Effects> currentEffects;
    public List<Effects.EffectType> effectedBy = new List<Effects.EffectType>();
    public GameObject destroyedPrefab;
    private bool destructible = true;
    private bool destroyed = false;
```

this is the class that holds the enum I am trying to set

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Effects 
{
    public bool usingEffect = false;
    public int effectOverTimeChance = 0;
    public EffectType effectType;
    public Stats.StatType effectedStat = Stats.StatType.health;
    public int minAmount;
    public int maxAmount;

 public enum EffectType
    {
        bleed,
        electric,
        fire,
        heal,
        physical,
        poison
    }
```

this is my JSON text this all works fine apart from that one enum effectedBy on the last entry

```
{
  "meleeWeapons": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "prefabID": "claw",
      "title": "claw",
      "description": "razor sharp claws",
      "slotType": 4,
      "effects": [
        {
          "effectType": 4,
          "minAmount": 2,
          "maxAmount": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "hammer",
      "description": "heavy and intimidating",
      "slotType": 4
    }
  ],
  "interactableObjects": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "prefabID": "BasicCrate",
      "title": "crate",
      "effectedBy": [
        {
          "effectType": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can work around this by changing effectedBy to a list of effects and giving the effect itself the enum value I require but if I could I would rather just keep it as the list of effectTypes.
Anybody have any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Effects.EffectType> effectedBy = new List<Effects.EffectType>();
```

is the main issue. That code says that you have a list (or array) of values of the type `EffectType`. Unfortunately, that is not the shape of your JSON:

```
"effectedBy": [
    {
      "effectType": 4
    }
]
```

That is an not an array of `EffectType`. It is an array of objects with an `effectType` property of type `EffectType`.

Thus you should instead use:

```
public List<EffectTypeWrapper> effectedBy = new List<EffectTypeWrapper>();
```

where `EffectTypeWrapper` is defined as:

```
public class EffectTypeWrapper
{
    public EffectType effectType { get; set; }
}
```

In future, I would strongly encourage use of https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp (example https://app.quicktype.io?share=4jOYgCbQhD7tmaJf10Ln).

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still struggling to understand why that's not working. I add another variable Effects.EffectType type and that works the way I would like it to. It's just the list form that does not

Comment: It isn't working @lukey_babes since an array of `EffectType` is **not** the same as an array of **objects** that have a `EffectType` property.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new interactableObject and just setting the effectedBy value then wrote that to JSON which gave the following.

```
{
"id": "",
"prefabID": "",
"title": "",
"description": "",
"itemPrefab": {
    "instanceID": 0
},
"myContainer": {
    "instanceID": 0
},
"health": {
    "current": 0.0,
    "minimum": 0.0,
    "maximum": 0.0,
    "rechargeRate": 0.0,
    "rechargeDelay": 0.0,
    "statType": 0
},
"effectedBy": [
    2
],
"type": 0,
"destroyedPrefab": {
    "instanceID": 0
}
```

}

Creating my interactableObject with my text file and assigning the enums without the effectType variable and just writing the enum value works as i was originally intending it to

```
"interactableObjects": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "prefabID": "BasicCrate",
      "title": "crate",
      "effectedBy": [
        2,
        4
      ],
    }
```

]

Comment: If changing the JSON was an option, it would have been better to make that clearer in your question.